# How does one connect a DPDT Push switch?

Tags: switches, schematics, altium, schematic, dpdt

I am using a [**MHPS2273**](https://www.digikey.com/en/htmldatasheets/production/53694/0/0/1/mh11) DPDT push button in my design. The purpose of this switch is to turn ON the device when I press the button. If I again press the button it will turn OFF the device. I am confused with the connections. Can anyone guide me?
[image]

Comment: Just use [something like this](https://vetco.net/products/dpdt-micro-push-on-push-off-switch). They are already built to do exactly what you want. Nothing else to add.

Comment: Are you confused with this switch because it does not work as expected in your circuit? Or are you confused with the symbol and the required wiring connections?

Answer (score 0):

Switches have two types of connections, poles and throws. A DPDT switch has two poles and for each pole there are two throws. The poles are the common connection, the throws are the switched connections. In your diagram you have a switch where the poles are labeled C1 and C2, the throws are A1, B1, A2 and B2. C1 switches between A1 and B1, it’s connected to one or the other. You need to have the poles  connected to what you want to switch yet they are shown as disconnected. You need to move the connections from either the A contacts or the B contacts to the C contacts.

Answer (score 0):

MHPS2273 is a latching DPDT key switch.

It appears that you require the two contacts to be connected in parallel.

The switch is to be wired as shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you state you want the first press to switch (and maintain) the ON state, then a second press should turn the circuit OFF. This is often known as a "Latching" switch, or in this case an "ON-ON" switch type. The [MHPS2273](https://www.digikey.com/en/htmldatasheets/production/53694/0/0/1/mh11) switch can perform this function, though being a DPDT type it is a bit of over-kill, (you have an extra throw and an extra pole, you could actually have used a SPDT or even a SPST latching switch type). However, connecting both poles of the switch in parallel will still work.  [Here](https://electronicsclub.info/switches.htm) is a good reference on different switch definitions.

As shown in your circuit the switch is not wired correctly. See the revised circuit below.
One connection should be made to the center common pin (C1) and the second connection to either pin 1A or 2A. In the revised circuit the switch connections could even be swapped and it would still perform the same function.

Do be careful about the exact P/N of your switch, the similar part ending with an "N" has a different action.

.
[image]